# Trouble binding an imploded array into a mysql prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am beating my head over the below syntax error.  I am trying to bind an imploded array into a prepared statement, but I am getting the following syntax error:

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1*

Here is my code.  Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
<?php 
include('config.php');

$selected = $_POST['selected'];

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM email_addresses WHERE email_addresses IN ?")) {

    $stmt->bind_param("s", "('" . implode("', '", $selected) . "')" );

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->close();

    print "ok";

} else {
    print $mysqli->error;
}

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

As a test, I tried:

```
print "('" . implode("', '", $selected) . "')";
```

Which correctly gives me

```
('me@me.com', 'you@you.com')
```

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer. I just wanted to say I think this is a neat trick. I could have used this technique for dynamic binds a few times myself.

Comment: @LeeLoftiss see my answer for why this won't work

Comment: I really just meant that I've often wanted to have dynamic bindings and it never occurred to me there would be a way. I often forget how versatile PHP is. I will be bookmarking your answer for next time I need this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me save you some trouble and tell you what you're trying to do won't work anyway. You are only binding one parameter to your `IN()` function call. You *think* you're passing a comma separated list but you are actually only passing a *comma separated string which is treated as one value*. This means you will be search for **one record** with a value of "'me@me.com', 'you@you.com'" instead of records that match "me@me.com" or "you@you.com".

To overcome this you need to:

1. Dynamically generate your types string
2. Use [`call_user_func_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) to bind your parameters

You can generate the types string like this:

```
$types = str_repeat('s', count($selected));
```

All this does is create a string of `s`'s that is as many characters as the number of elements in the array.

You would then bind your parameters using `call_user_func_array()` like this (notice I put the parenthesis back in for the `IN()` function):

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM email_addresses WHERE email_addresses IN (?)")) {
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), array_merge($types, $selected));
```

But if you try this you will get an error about `mysqli_stmt::bind_param()` expecting parameter two to be passed by reference:

> Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given

This is kind of annoying but easy enough to work around. To work around that you can use the following function:

```
function refValues($arr){ 
    $refs = array(); 
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) 
        $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key]; 
    return $refs; 
}
```

It just creates an array of values that are references to the values in the `$selected` array. This is enough to make `mysqli_stmt::bind_param()` happy:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM email_addresses WHERE email_addresses IN (?)")) {
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), array_merge($types, refValues($selected)));
```

**Edit**

As of PHP 5.6 you can now use the `...` operator to make this even simpler:

```
$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$selected);
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you very much for explaining. I am no longer receiving any MySQL errors, but the email_addresses are not being deleted from the database for some reason. I wonder, do they need to be surrounded by quotations as they are strings?

Comment: Nope. The quotes are only used for interpreted statements. For prepared statements that are not needed. If you have access to your query log you can see your SQL query and verify it looks correct and use it for testing. I wish mysqli offered a way to get the query run but apparently no one else thinks it would be a useful feature to have.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not.  I am working on a client's site that is hosted by GoDaddy. I'm sure that I will figure it out, it's just a question of how long!

Comment: Hopefully this got you closer. Good luck! And if you notice something to improve in this code let me know so I can post it for others who stumble across this later.

Comment: Well explained answer, John. Thanks. Can you explain more about the $types variable.