# Parse SQL Query to get values from 'implode'

Tags: php, html, mysql, implode

I have statements like this :

```
$q1="SELECT * FROM indexing WHERE keywords IN '(".implode(' , ' , $words). ")";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$q1) ;
```

I need to get details from `indexing` table based on the values in the variable `$words`. 
But now its always showing the returned number of rows as zero. 
How to add the quotes properly in the sql statement in order to get the correct result.

Comment: Have you printed the q1 before execution?

Comment: Have you checked the return value of your query for errors?

Comment: yes..its showing <code>SELECT * FROM indexing WHERE keywords IN '(1)</code>

Comment: but when i give echo implode(',', array_keys($words)); its showing the array elements correctly

Answer (score 1):

If you `echo` (or `vardump` or `printf`) `q1`, for debugging, you would see the actual SQL text being sent to the server.

There's a few problems here. There's a single quote before the paren, we expect that you intend `$words` to be array, which is to be converted into a list of string literals in the SQL statement.

```
IN '(".implode(' , ' , $words). ")"
   ^           ^^ ^^
```

It looks like you intended something like this:

```
IN ('" . implode("','",$words) . "')";
    ^            ^^ ^^            ^
```

---

If `$words` is empty, that will result in SQL text:

```
IN ('')
```

If `$words` contains elements `"abc","def"`, that will result in SQL text:

```
IN ('abc','def')
```

But again, examine the contents of the actual SQL text before it's sent to the database.

---

You may want to seriously consider the resulting SQL statement if one of the elements in `$words` happens to contain characters that could be interpreted as SQL text, for example:

```
"abc') OR 1=1; -- "
```

Classic SQL Injection vulnerability ala Little Bobby Tables http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

say you have,

```
$words = ["a" ,"b","c","d"];  // i.e an array
```

then,

```
$val = implode(',' , $words) ; 


$q1="SELECT * FROM indexing WHERE keywords IN ($val)";
```

Do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , you are using mysqli_query whereas you should be using prepared statements at least if not pdo.

`$query = "SELECT <your code>  FROM <your code> IN ('".implode("','",array_values($words))."') ";` should work.
And if you are looking for a solution in prepared statement, it has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110886/trouble-binding-an-imploded-array-into-a-mysql-prepared-statement).