# php variable won't work, but hardcoded numbers will, why?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a url that looks like this: website.com?id=1,2

```
    $urlParam = $_GET['id']; 
    echo $urlParam;
```

$urlParam returns 1,2 as expected. However....i'm trying to use it to query a mysql database (I think that's the right phrase for what i'm doing??). This works:

```
    $query->where(array(
       'id:IN' => array(1,2)
    ));
```

This does not work:

```
    $query->where(array(
       'id:IN' => array($urlParam)
    ));
```

I don't get it! Why?? Also...I barely have any idea what i'm doing, so I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do all this but this is what I was able to come up with.

Comment: Do: `var_dump($urlParam);` and `var_dump(["I'm an array"]);` and look at the output of both, especially what type they have. <- Then you should see what the difference is and where you are going wrong

Comment: Doesn't look like you use plain MySQLi or PDO. Which framework (or helper class) do you use?

Comment: I'm creating a snippet in MODX, Google says it uses a framework called xPDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert string into array you can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function:

```
$query->where(array(
   'id:IN' => explode(',',$urlParam)
));
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `1,2` is *not* seen as a comma delimited value by MySQL. It see it as a string with a value of "1,2". You have no rows matching that value so you get no results.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110886/trouble-binding-an-imploded-array-into-a-mysql-prepared-statement/20111044#20111044) for how to work around this.

Comment: I now understand why it was not working. That makes sense. The workaround was a bit too complex for me, though. Luckily someone had an easier solution

Answer (score 1):

You could set it so that rather than a string, it's an array.
Ie.

```
<form method="GET">
<input name="test[]" value="1" />
<input name="test[]" value="2" />
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
print_r($_GET);
?>
```

This will show up in your url as:

```
www.myurl.com?test%5B%5D=1&test%5B%5D=2
```