# MYSQL SELECT statement with variable based on PHP loop

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

```
for ($i=1;$i<5;$i++) //Loop read & save all vars from fieldform
{
    if (array_key_exists('country'.$i, $_POST) == true)
    {
            ${"country".$i} = $_POST['country'.$i];

            $get_id = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT country_id FROM country WHERE country_pl = '{$country[$i]}'");
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_id);
            $country_id = $row['country_id'];
            echo $country_id; 
    }
}
```

This is a loop for read & save country name selected in form field. Everything works fine, beside MYSQL QUERY. I don't know how to write `'{$country[$i]}'` properly in a MySQL statement.

Comment: Please refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  You should at the least provide us with what you expect to feed to this code, and what response you expect to be getting out of it. You aren't describing what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use variable variables, use an array.

```
$country[$i] = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['country'.$i]);
```

Then you can do:

```
$get_id = mysqlil_query($connection, "SELECT country_id FROM country WHERE country_pl = '{$country[$i]}'");
```

Comment: I also wonder why you're not using an array for the inputs. If you name the inputs `name=country[]` instead of `name=country1`, etc., `$_POST['country']` will be an array of all the country inputs.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to run one query instead of one every iteration. I would suggest:

```
$countries = array();
for ($i=1;$i<5;$i++) //Loop read & save all vars from fieldform
{
    if (array_key_exists('country'.$i, $_POST))
    {
        $countries[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['country'.$i]);
    }
}

$get_id = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT country_id FROM country WHERE country_pl IN ('" . implode ("', '", $countries) . "')");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_id)) {
    $country_id = $row['country_id'];
    echo $country_id;
}
```

Ideally you should use a prepared statement, but that's a bit more tricky: see [Trouble binding an imploded array into a mysql prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110886/trouble-binding-an-imploded-array-into-a-mysql-prepared-statement)